# How to pass multiple executable in ansible within a shell module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to pass a prompt y in ansible when it executes command.
When i do manually on server it asks for a prompt.

The issue is for command to run i need to pass the executable /bin/bash 
*command: `source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply`* for expect command to run  i need to pass /usr/bin/expect .

My question, how can i pass 2 executable in ansible such that for command it uses /bin/bash and for expect prompt it should use /usr/bin/expect and the error is because i am using source, what is an alternative i can use?

Update: I dont know why but i am not able to pass --ignore-prompt , It gives an error

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx:~$ tsm pending-changes apply --ignore-prompt
Unrecognized option: --ignore-prompt
```

Please help me with a solution!

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx:~$ tsm pending-changes apply
This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?
(y/n):
```

My ansible script:

```
  shell: |
     source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply
     expect "This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?\n(y/n):"
     send "y\n"
     exit 0
  args:
     executable: /usr/bin/expect
      args:
         executable: /bin/bash/expect
      when: inventory_hostname == "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
```

ERROR:

```
 changed: [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply\n expect \"This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?\\n(y/n):\"\n send \"y\\n\"\n exit 0",
    "delta": "0:00:00.034824",
    "end": "2018-08-20 17:29:41.457700",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply\n expect \"This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?\\n(y/n):\"\n send \"y\\n\"\n exit 0",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": "/usr/bin/expect",
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2018-08-20 17:29:41.422876",
    "stderr": "wrong # args: should be \"source ?-encoding name? fileName\"\n    while executing\n\"source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply\"",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "wrong # args: should be \"source ?-encoding name? fileName\"",
        "    while executing",
        "\"source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply\""
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by passing an -r option.

```
- name: Initialize and Start Tableau Server
  shell: source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply -r -u ubuntu -p '{{ tableau_server_admin_password }}'

  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  when: inventory_hostname == "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are doing far too much with bash commands and '&&' inside command, none of this feels idempotent.

Can I recommend going back to the drawing board with this. I would recommend creating the command using the 'creates' parameter so it can tell if it needs to run.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/command_module.html

Or alternatively check before hand which will then see if the command needs running using register.

In this instance of your issue with the:

`tsm pending-changes apply`

should support as per https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/cli_pending-changes.htm

`tsm pending-changes apply --ignore-prompt`

which will then not prompt for a yes and will not need the expect module.

Comment: but when i passed shell: source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply --ignore-prompt
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
it gave me an error 
"stdout_lines": [
        "Unrecognized option: --ignore-prompt"

Comment: if i do on the server i am getting this error , so i need to pass it ansible as prompt ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx:/bin$ tsm pending-changes apply --ignore-prompt
Unrecognized option: --ignore-prompt

Comment: I guess this is just a version thing. Glad to see I steered you in the right direction anyway!